# Extracting XML in VBA from Oracle DB

Tags: sql, vba, database, oracle

I have an Oracle DB that contains an XML Column called `CONTENT` of this kind:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PAGE>
  <INFO>
    <ID>324374</ID>
    <PAGE>ANE_CSC</PAGE>
  </INFO>
  <CAMPS>
    <CAMP KEY_CAMP="ACCESS_CONTROL">456675</CAMP>
    <CAMP KEY_CAMP="IDEN_ANAG">1458</CAMP>...
  </CAMPS>
</PAGE>
```

I'm trying to extract the `IDEN_ANAG` value (so: `1458`) in a Excel cell, however I've no idea how to elaborate XML data correctly in VBA.

I have tried a few things (commands like `getStringVal(), getClob(), EXTRACT()`) and cannot figure out a solution that would work.

This is what I'm currently trying to do:

```
Cmd.CommandText = "select XMLTYPE('<CAMP>'||CONTENT||'</CAMP>').getStringVal() from table WHERE ID = 324374
Set rs = Cmd.Execute()

Do While Not rs.EOF
    WSP1.Cells(CellWrite, 1).Value = rs.Fields(0).Value
    
    CellWrite = CellWrite + 1
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

I know that the code above isn't actually extracting the specific ID, but I'm fairly desparate to at least start with extracting the whole XML and then trying to find a solution for just specific part of it.

While I'm almost sure that I'm just making a mistake in the code, I've tried several different results based on internet searches, using different functions etc and I've always run into errors like `Runtime error` or the code above gives me the error as `Runtime error: Character string buffer too small`.

Any suggestions on how to extract the specific data would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proper XML parser. You can either use the query:

```sql
SELECT iden_anag
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         '/PAGE/CAMPS'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( t.content )
         COLUMNS
           iden_anag NUMBER PATH './CAMP[@KEY_CAMP="IDEN_ANAG"]'
       )
WHERE  id = 324374
```

or

```sql
SELECT XMLQUERY(
         '/PAGE/CAMPS/CAMP[@KEY_CAMP="IDEN_ANAG"]/text()'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( content )
         RETURNING CONTENT
       ) AS iden_anag
FROM   table_name
WHERE  id = 324374
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id NUMBER, content CLOB );

INSERT INTO table_name ( id, content ) VALUES (
  324374,
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PAGE>
  <INFO>
    <ID>324374</ID>
    <PAGE>ANE_CSC</PAGE>
  </INFO>
  <CAMPS>
    <CAMP KEY_CAMP="ACCESS_CONTROL">456675</CAMP>
    <CAMP KEY_CAMP="IDEN_ANAG">1458</CAMP>...
  </CAMPS>
</PAGE>'
);
```

Both output:

> ```
> | IDEN_ANAG |
> | --------: |
> |      1458 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f05db469d7daf909a7228b30d4753519)*

Comment: First of all thank you with helping. However there seems to be a wall of some kind somewhere. I've tried to apply both variants to the full code and I'm getting issues on both. The first variant with ```CROSS APPLY``` gives me the error ```ORA-00905: Missing keyword``` which keep in mind might be because I'm inside a SQL string and ```@KEY_CAMP```uses quotes inside quotes. (I tried to escape with ```=""IDEN_ANAG""``` yet, it doesn't work. The second variant gives me the: ```Type "xquery external variable" unknown```. Is it possible the method of extraction after the SQL itself needs to change?

Comment: @Tree `CROSS APPLY` works from Oracle 12c. If you are on an old version of Oracle then use `CROSS JOIN` instead. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2d25e06cb8b4d8b90cdf2e2839a35591)

Comment: Hello, I've tried to modify variant 2 you had offered by removing ```PASSING XMLTYPE(CONTENT)``` to simply ```PASSING CONTENT``` (n.b. CONTENT in my database is called differently) and adding at the very end ```.getStringVal()``` which finally returned the value I needed in an excel cell! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Tree This is one problem when if you'd given us the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) and DML (`INSERT`) statements for your table and sample data (rather than just giving a brief English description and a text representation of the data, which can be misunderstood) then we might have been able to give a better solution as removing the `XMLTYPE` would create issues based on the data I've used in my example but it solves your problem which suggests that we both have used different ways of storing the data. Clearing up all the issues with setting up the environment can make getting an answer much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It is an Oracle error and appears when you try to put some big string into `VARCHAR` datatype.

You can check [this documentation article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb04cre.htm#i1024803), section "Selecting XML Data Using XMLType Methods":

> You can select XMLType data using PL/SQL, C, or Java. You can also use the XMLType methods `getClobVal()`, `getStringVal()`, `getNumberVal()`, and `getBlobVal(csid)` to retrieve XML data as a `CLOB`, `VARCHAR`, `NUMBER`, and `BLOB` value, respectively.

So looks like your data is too big to fit in `VARCHAR` that `getStringVal()` returns, and you need to use `getClobVal()`.

Also there's no need to create XML data by concatenation since it cannot handle all the serialization specifics (like symbols used in XML should be converted) and you can also face the same limitation of `VARCHAR` length on concatenation. You need [`XMLElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions220.htm) function for this:

> ```
> select
>   xmlelement("Current_date", sysdate) as date_xml,
>   xmlelement("SpecialSymbols", 'Symbols > and < need conversion') as spec_symbols_xml
> from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> DATE_XML                                | SPEC_SYMBOLS_XML                                                      
> :-------------------------------------- | :---------------------------------------------------------------------
> <Current_date>2021-03-05</Current_date> | <SpecialSymbols>Symbols &gt; and &lt; need conversion</SpecialSymbols>
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3f311cac7c54f0fba8580a574f619206)*

You can chech a bunch of [XML manipulation functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html) to build XML, so use them instead of string manipulations.
For example, get query results as XML:

> ```
> select
>   dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select object_name, object_type from all_objects where rownum < 3') as result_clob
> from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> | RESULT_CLOB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | <?xml version="1.0"?><br><ROWSET><br> <ROW><br>  <OBJECT_NAME>ORA$BASE</OBJECT_NAME><br>  <OBJECT_TYPE>EDITION</OBJECT_TYPE><br> </ROW><br> <ROW><br>  <OBJECT_NAME>DUAL</OBJECT_NAME><br>  <OBJECT_TYPE>TABLE</OBJECT_TYPE><br> </ROW><br></ROWSET><br> |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=700a2d319e4b527f2f6b099dc87dee93)*

But it is better to do all MXL manipulations in the database and retrieve plain results to VBA.